# Visual Studio TFS Merge omits all custom fields and associated work items

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, merge, tfvc, team-explorer

Why does TFS only merge files and Comments when there can be an arbitrary number of additional fields? Can this behavior be changed?

[image]

Our check-in policy requires these other fields to be set, but having to manually copy them over defeats the purpose of using automation (the merge tool).

[image]

Also, if I preemptively have *any* of these fields manually copied over, those are then deleted (even when identical)... So because I tried to manually associate the work items I knew it wouldn't for me, it unset them, so I have to do it yet again.

This applies to both VS 2015 and 2017, on TFS 2015

Answer (score 1):

It is what it is. The behavior you want is not how it was implemented.

There are a couple of extensions on the marketplace that add some of what you want:

- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AdamLove.MergeChangeset2019
- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KulikovDenis.AutoMergeforVisualStudio2017
- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DieterVantilt.teammerge

The idea is that by following the merge tree you can derive the information. Why would you duplicate the content from one commit to another?

As you can see Team Explorer is extensible, creating or extending one of these existing extensions to match your process is entirely possible.